# Can´t register a user using Firebase authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I´m trying to create an Activity with the Firebase authentication, but it´s wrong and I don´t know why.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private EditText editTextMobile;
private Button btn_register;

private FirebaseAuth auth;
private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    // Elementos del XML
    btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);


    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onRegisterClick();
        }
    });

    changeStatusBarColor();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser != null){
        reload();
    }
}

public void onRegisterClick() {

    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = editTextEmail.getText().toString();

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MenuPrincipalActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.stay);

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void changeStatusBarColor() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.register_bk_color));

    }
}

private void reload() { }
```

I´ve tried to includ the onRegisterClick method into the onClick, but it throws me an error.

Also I tried to parse the EditText to String, but I don´t know if the error is there.

Although, I can´t use the Firebase Assistant, it´s always loading. I´ve tried to uncheck the plugins and check it again, but it doesn´t work too.

Comment: `but it throws me an error.` research the error, change your code, problem solved. finding and posting your stack trace here is the most useful thing you can do, but you should first research what it says before doing that

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact error message you get and its stack trace.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.